# Activating Vue that is within a template rendered by a Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, vue.js

I am stuck in a situation where the (Laravel) Controller is providing a view to insert into the frontend using Ajax like this:

**MyController.php**

```
return Response::json(['html' => View::make('my_blade_view', [
            'items' => $items
        ])->render()]);
```

Within my_blade_view.blade.php, I need to add some Vue.js functionality, like this:

**my_blade_view.blade.php**

```
<div v-on:click="myVueMethod"></div>
```

The problem is, when the Ajax call completes, although the HTML from my_blade_view.blade.php is successfully inserted into the page (which is another Blade view), the v-on:click functionality does not run.  I am wondering if there is a way I can tell the Vue instance to re-process the page when the Ajax call completes so that it picks up the new Vue code I have added in the template which was rendered by the Controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [$mount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) to handle this.

What you'll have to do is declare the component in the `MyController.php` but don't mount it to any html elements.  Then once your `ajax` call completes and the `html` from `my_blade_view.blade.php` is added to the `dom` then call `$mount(elementSelector)`.

Here's a simple example that shows how to mount to an element after the instance has already been created.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  }
})

setTimeout(function(){
  vm.$mount("#app");
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, without knowing the situation, could you just push `my_blade_view.blade.php` into `MyController.php` and hide it with `v-if` instead of loading it with ajax?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll take a look soon

Comment: lameleon unfortunately I do not believe either of your solutions will work for me, at least not as-is.  For your first solution, I think I need something that will work closer to this: https://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/g5xx35Lx/3/

Comment: @user3089840 Essentially the same thing.  You just have a couple syntax and logic errors.  Here check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p4cgp7bw/).

Comment: I'm going to give you a point because you are getting me closer, and I really appreciate the help, but the problem is that the Vue instance has to already have the line with the `el: '#app',` in it before the new content gets added and has to be "re-mounted"

Comment: @user3089840  Would [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) maybe fit your case better?